# Get the image and SHA image ID of images in pod on Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I get the image ID (the docker sha256 hash) of a image / container within a Kubernetes deployment?

Comment: Kubernetes identifies the container by `k8s_<service-name>_<pod-name>_<namespace>_<unknow-code>`. That is pretty much enough to identify a container by service name, pod name and it namespace. So you can get the ID of a container by `sudo docker ps -a  -q --no-trunc --filter="name=k8s_<service-name>_<pod-name>_<namespace>"`. eg. `sudo docker ps -a  -q --no-trunc --filter="name=k8s_admin-dashboard_admin-dashboard-1561008181-554pw_default"`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick (you must have `jq` installed):

```
$ kubectl get pod --namespace=xx yyyy -o json | jq '.status.containerStatuses[] | { "image": .image, "imageID": .imageID }'
{
  "image": "nginx:latest",
  "imageID": "docker://sha256:b8efb18f159bd948486f18bd8940b56fd2298b438229f5bd2bcf4cedcf037448"
}
{
  "image": "eu.gcr.io/zzzzzzz/php-fpm-5:latest",
  "imageID": "docker://sha256:6ba3fe274b6110d7310f164eaaaaaaaaaa707a69df7324a1a0817fe3b475566a"
}
```

Comment: I love `jq`; as an additional trick (since the poster asked specifically about the sha) if your version of `jq` is new enough: `{the_sha: .imageID|capture("docker://(?<s>sha256.+)").s}`, or you can use `match("docker://(sha256.+)").captures[0].string` in older versions; finally, in the specific example you used, `jq` is ecma5-esque in that if your dest key and source key are named the same, the syntax `{image, imageID}` will do what you think

Comment: oh, and as much as I love `jq`, don't forget that `kubectl` has two different output templating languages, so if you _only_ have `kubectl`, it'll be hella verbose but you can use `-o go-template='{{a ton of text here}}'` or `-o jsonpath='more text with bizarre syntax'`

Comment: Seems the JSON has changed with the newest version. The following seems to work instead now: `kubectl get pods -o json | jq '.items[] .status.containerStatuses[] | { "image": .image, "imageID": .imageID }'`

Answer (score 23):

An example without jq usage.

Using **jsonpath**:

`kubectl get pods $YOUR_POD_NAME -o jsonpath="{..imageID}"`

Using **go-templates**

`kubectl get pods $YOUR_POD_NAME -o go-template --template="{{ range .status.containerStatuses }}{{ .imageID }}{{end}}"`

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-containers-filtering-by-pod-namespace

Comment: Why was this  downvoted? Works like a charm and much better than with jq

Comment: I think it's because i misread question and my answer haven't provided a hash, only full image name. Thanks to @evan, i corrected my answer and removed go-templates part, since its not possible to get hash info from it.

Comment: actually, after rereading Janos answer i came with go-templates solution as well, so it's back :D

Comment: Upvoted.  I love jq, too.  But less is more.  :--)

Answer (score 6):

Right way to do this:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath="{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[*].imageID}" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest one to use is:

For getting images SHA value of all the pods in a single namespace:

- `kubectl get pods -n <your-namespace> -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}'`

For getting images SHA value of all the pods in all the namespace:

- `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.name}{":\t"}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.image}{", "}{end}{end}'`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another version, with a few twists (using `--selector` and YAML) and to me the most memorable one, as using generic Bash tools (incl. `cut` on colons) :

```
# if there is only one pod:
$ kubectl get pod -o yaml | grep sha | cut -d ":" -f 3

# when selecting among multiple pods: 
$ kubectl get pod --selector app=ml-scraper -o yaml | grep sha | cut -d ":" -f 3
```