# How to pass as environment variable the digest of the Docker image used to the container, in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running a Docker image using Kubernetes. I would like to pass to the container the digest of the image being used. So that the code inside the container can use this for debugging/logging. The problem is that I do not seem to be able to find a way to do this without hard-coding the image digest into the pod configuration.

Is there a way to define pod configuration way so that it dynamically passes the digest as environment variable for whichever version of Docker image it ends up using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever Kubernetes happens to know can be injected using the [downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/).  That set of data is in [the API reference for Pod objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#pod-v1-core).

It looks like this should work:

```
env:
  - name: DOCKER_IMAGE_ID
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.containerStatuses[0].imageID
```

You may prefer to inject the `spec.containers[0].image` name, which will be easier to understand after the fact.  If you're using a tool like [Helm](https://helm.sh/) to generate the configuration, you can also use its values system:

```
image: {{ .Values.image }}:{{ .Values.tag }}
env:
  - name: DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG
    value: {{ .Values.tag }}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `imageID` Docker's image digest? Or something else?

Comment: "`imageID` (_string_): ImageID of the container's image."  I _think_ that's the Docker SHA-256 image hash.

Comment: It seems it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612310/get-the-image-and-image-id-of-images-in-pod-on-kubernetes-deployment

Comment: It seems this is not really possible. Downward API is limited [in what it can expose](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/#capabilities-of-the-downward-api) and there are open issues about this: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50309 and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/80346